# PerfMon Counters missing

Tags: windows-7, perfmon

On my System (Win7 Ultimate x64, purchased & Installed in German(y), UI set to English), a lot of vital performance counters seem to be missing.

When starting perfmon, I get the following message:

```
---------------------------
Performance Monitor Control
---------------------------
Unable to add these counters:

\Memory\Available MBytes
\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use
\Memory\Cache Faults/sec
\Memory\Cache Faults/sec
\PhysicalDisk(*)\% Idle Time
\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk Queue Length
\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The Groups "Memory", "Physical Disk" don't exist, and no other groups that contain such counters.

Running perfon with domain admin credentials gives the same results.

I'd like to have my counters back :)
(I especially need memory and disk)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to rebuild the performance monitors you have to run

lodctr /r  (in your command line)

More details [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19374.windows-performance-monitor-unable-to-add-these-counters.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This behavior may occur if certain extensible counters corrupt the registry, or if some Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)-based programs modify the registry.

Back to the top

Rebuild the base performance counters
Extensible counter information is stored in both of the following locations:

- The following registry subkey:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESoftwareMicrosoftWindows NTCurrent VersionPerflib09
- The %Systemroot%System32Perfc009.dat file and the %Systemroot%System32Perfh009.dat file
  To rebuild the base performance counter libraries manually, follow these steps:

  1. Expand the Perfc009.dat file and the Perfh009.dat file. These files are located on the Windows Installation Disc. The compressed files are found at DriveLetter:i386perfc009.da_ and at DriveLetter:i386perfh009.da_. Replace the files that are in the %Systemroot%System32 folder.
  2. Start Registry Editor, and then locate the following key in the registry:
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESoftwareMicrosoftWindows NTCurrentVersionPerflib
  3. In the registry, change the LastCounter value to 1846 (decimal), and change the LastHelp value to 1847 (decimal).
  4. Locate the following registry key to search for services that have a Performance subkey:
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESystemCurrentControlSetServices
  5. Remove the following values from the Performance subkey (if they exist):
- FirstCounter
- FirstHelp
- LastCounter
- LastHelp

From [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/add-counters-windows-7s-performance-monitor/)

Answer (score 0):

The [suggested fix](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19374.windows-performance-monitor-unable-to-add-these-counters.aspx) for this is to:

1. Run CMD as an administrator.
2. Change the working directory to System32: `cd C:\Windows\System32`
3. Rebuild your resource counters: `lodctr /r`

For some users, that works fine. Others may instead receive the message:

`Error: Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system backup store, error code is 2`

If that happens, then [the fix](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9b01e1a6-d872-4f28-9280-f35d6ca02a9f/lodctr-r-error-code-2?forum=w7itprogeneral) is to:

1. Change the working directory to SysWOW64: `cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64`
2. Rebuild your resource counters: `lodctr /R`